# I am having trouble with running my calculator app on android

Tags: java, android, gradle

$ adb shell am start -n "me.zanecoleriley.calculator/me.zanecoleriley.calculator.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 7940 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: me.zanecoleriley.calculator, PID: 7940
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyc.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:33)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
        ... 10 more
```

I've tried to fix it to no avail

Comment: You say you "tried to fix it to no avail" but what was it you actually did? You know we can't see you from here, don't you? Did you follow the link and read and follow the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file? Also try to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` over your application tag.

If that does not help, than you can also try out this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html